# How to search in lightswitch for integer fields

Tags: lightswitch-2013

how can i create a search in lightswitch to search for an integer field ? I was able to do this for string fields, but I couldn't do this for integers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

when you click "Edit Query" on the left panel in VS2013, You are displayed with 3 options.

1. Filter
2. Sort
3. Parameters

Filter contains 4 separate columns, so in your case it would look something like this:

[image]

The "OrderSearch" is the parameter which you are going to use as your Search box on the screen.

Now on your Browse screen lets say, if you expand the table view on the left, you should see the OrderID parameter you have just created, if you drag this across the you screen, you can make this a text box and can use it to search for integer values, as you do with string values.

The important bits are to make sure the Paramater is an integer:
[image]

and this can be changed in the properties window at the bottom right of the screen to optional, which is best for browse screens.

also if the filter option's are wrong it will mean that the parameter will not work. an example is Firstname, Surname and age, there are 2 strings and 1 integer so the filter options would be set up as **WHERE** (Firstname) **OR** (Surname) **AND** (age)

multiple filters can use the same parameter field also as long as they are the same data type, i.e. firstname and surname

any questions please ask, and hope this helps